# Yii2 get related data in Model by a hasMany relation

Tags: attributes, yii2, relation

In Model, when I have a hasMany relation, can I somehow get the values of a certain attribute concatenated? Is there something like that?

```
public function getRelatedManyAttribute() {
    return $this->relatedMany->concat('attributeMany');
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with attribute concatenated?

Comment: by a hasMany, there are more than one records, so I would get eg. ids like an array back and that would I like to implode them, that in the end I get a result something like this: 845, 96354, 47

Comment: Have you generated the models with gii?

Comment: I've generated with Giiant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if I understood you cerrectly, but if you want all the values of the same attribute of a 1:n-relation it could be this simple oneliner:

```
public function getIdsConcatenated() {
    return implode(', ', ArrayHelper::getColumn($this->myManyRelation, 'id'));
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: How to add a conditon to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this -

```
  public function getSubMenuMenu()
{
     return $this->hasMany(Your_table_name::className(), ['id' => 'your_column_name']);;
}
```

for more understanding visit [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/780/drills-search-by-a-has_many-relation-in-yii-2-0/)

Comment: This is a relation, and that's already defined in my model. The question is, how can I access an attribute of the related model, concatenated if there are many.